# Localised variable shows up as Global

Tags: scoping

Why does this local variable show up as Global?

```
?q
```

> Information::notfound: Symbol q not found. >>

```
f[] := Module[{q}, Null]

?[q]
```

> Global`q

This causes a shadowing warning when the the code below is run subsequently.  (The `q` variables are not supposed to be connected in any way.  They're just the same variable name.)

```
BeginPackage["test`"];
test;
q
Begin["`Private`"];
test[] := Module[{}, q = 1]
End[];
EndPackage[]
```

> q::shdw: Symbol q appears in multiple contexts {test`,Global`}; definitions in context test` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>
>
> q

**Edit**

Apparently this is a normal effect of parsing input.  The shadowing can be avoided by removing `q`, e.g.:-

[image]

Comment: I edited your [tag:localization] into [tag:scoping]. Localization, as I think it's normally understood, would mean adjustments of e.g. date and time formats for a particular (geopolitical) locale. The computer science concept is scoping, although the text of your question obviously makes it clear to which you are referring.

Comment: Also, worth noting that `Module` here produces a symbol in the `Global\`` context in any case; it is just not called `q` but rather `Symbol["q$"<>ToString[$ModuleNumber]]`. If you want to create a symbol with a context, I think the best way is probably to use `Unique`. (Specify `Temporary` attribute to fully replicate `Module` behavior.)

Comment: Can you showcase  a shadowing problem MWE?

Comment: I just marked this question as a duplicate.  Please review that action and let me know if you believe it is incorrect.

Comment: @Yves - added a showcase.

Comment: Your present example code does not include `q` as a variable to be localized by `Module` -- is that intentional?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - yes, the first q in `f[]` is localised but the one in the `test` package isn't.  I'd have thought the first one would be q$123 so the second one wouldn't have shadowed.

Comment: I see that there is a reopen vote; is it yours?

Comment: No, someone else. This issue is indeed addressed in your link.

Comment: Chris, your edited question is quite different from your original one. Are you satisfied with the information you have the answers? I haven't voted to reopen because I'm a bit unsure whether it isn't still a duplicate.

Comment: @halirutan - yes, the answer was suitably informative.

Answer (score 3):

The `q` in `Information[q]`, although different from the `q` localized in `Module` is indeed a `Global` variable.  In fact, try any variable you like and you will get the same result, provided that the `Context` of your notebook is `Global`.

```
Information[x]
(* Global`x *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I was using `?` earlier, but tried `Information` for clarity.  Didn't realise it would work differently.  I'm still getting a shadowing problem though.

Answer (score 3):

What you see here happens because *Mathematica* does *see* this symbol during evaluation. As far as I know, *Mathematica* has, as many compilers/interpreters, a symbol table where it puts all symbols that it has seen during an evaluation.

If you know this, it becomes instantly obvious what the output of

```
Information[ohwhatthehell]
```

is. Or that here

```
1 /. omfg_ :> 2
```

even the symbol that is hidden in a pattern makes its way into the symbol table.

```
Names["Global`*"]
(* {"ohwhatthehell", "omfg", ...} *)
```

To remove a symbol from the symbol table you can use, well, `Remove`

```
Remove[omfg]
Names["Global`*"]
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question.  I think you have a point in that one of many interpreters is warning me about shadowing, except the new variable is not in Global; it is localised as shown.  Is it still `q` or `q$123`?  I wonder.